# I wanted to do a Binary search but the result is faulty

Tags: python, binary-search

I wanted to do binary search on a list but the result shows 'false' even if I check a number from the list.

```
def clist(a):

    l = [2,6,5,9,7,1,4,8,3]
    newl = sorted(l)
    check = int(1+len(newl)/2)

    if newl[check] == a:
        return True

    if check > a:
        for x in newl[:check]:
            if x == a:
                return True
            return False

    if check < a:
        for x in newl[check::]:
            if x == a:
                return True
            return False

print(clist(7))
```

Comment: This isn't binary search anyway. You split the list once, then revert to linear search. Proper binary search would continue to split the list in halves until only one element remains.

Comment: But if you are sorting the list as part of the routine, you are traversing all of it anyway. Binary search really only makes sense when you already know the input is sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your script in such a way that:

1. take the element at the middle of the list
2. return it if that's what you need
3. if your `needle` is gt than the middle, then call `bsearch` on the remaining right side of the list
4. othwewise call `bsearch` with the left side

```js
def bsearch(needle, haystack):
    l = len(haystack)
    half = int(l / 2)
    element = haystack[half];

    if element == needle:
        return element

    if needle <= element:
        return bsearch(needle, haystack[0:half])

    if needle > element:
        return bsearch(needle, haystack[half:l])




print(bsearch(7, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
```

---

in binary search:

1. list must be ordered
2. as stated by @tripleee, you have to recursively split the list in halves

Comment: This code doesn't work for cases where the needle isn't in the haystack. Try `bsearch(1, [0, 2, 3])` (which gives a `RecursionError`) and bsearch(0, [1, 2, 3])` (which gives an `IndexError`). It looks  as though the OP wanted something that returns `True` if the item is in the list,  and `False` otherwise. But more than that, the OP wants to know what's wrong with *their* code. None of the answers here seem to address that.

Comment: Hi, mine was just a quick hint on how to write `b search`, it doesn't handle any edge case (which I assumed easy to be added though). It is also easy to return `True/False`... The whole scope of my answer was to show the logic behind the algorithm itself (recursively calling bsearch with halves of the initial input). and that is what is wrong with the op's code

Answer (score 1):

Please go through this:

```
def clist(a):

    l = [2,6,5,9,7,1,4,8,3]
    newl = sorted(l)
    check = int(1+len(newl)/2)

    if newl[check] == a:
        return True

    if newl[check] > a:              #fixed the bug here
        for x in newl[:check]:
            if x == a:
                return True

    if newl[check] < a:             #fixed the bug here
        for x in newl[check:]:
            if x == a:
                return True

    return False        #Return false should be universal. When the entire search fails it should be called.

print(clist(7))
```

Comment: How does this answer help the OP?  It looks like what you're trying to do is ask a question or make a comment ("Can you please go over what this code is doing?" or "Please describe what the code does and why.").

Comment: Added the comments. Hope that helps. 1. Probably it should go in comments 2. May  be the OP is learning phase of Binary Search. That's why I did not give an explicit answer to it. I just fixed the bugs

Comment: Unfortunately, what you have is not a binary search. :-(

Comment: And you're right, the OP could be learning about it (and in fact, there's a strong chance that this is true), but presenting code is giving an explicit answer, so adding words about what you did doesn't change that.  It just makes the answer more readable (which is a good thing). :-)

Comment: Your script is no longer logarithmic as soon as it doesn’t match the first if statement

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not binary search, you are checking element by element of a sorted list after checking the middle element.

```
def binary_search(arr, i):
    n = len(arr)
    arr = sorted(arr)
    left = 0
    right = n - 1

    # Define the condition when the loop should be broken 
    while (left <= right):
        mid = left + (right-left) // 2
        if arr[mid] == i:
            return True
        elif arr[mid] < i:
            left = mid + 1 
        else:
            right = mid - 1
    return False

l = [2,6,5,9,7,1,4,8,3]
i = 7
binary_search(l, i)
```

Comment: I saw all the answers and comments and I learned something from each of them. I'm a newbie to coding. Now, I understood what is binary search. Thanks.